# Select too long blob data gives weird result

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, varchar2

I am trying to run the below query in SQL developer which gives weird result in the output:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(message,100))
from XML_MESSAGE;
```

My problem is that the result shows the correct XML message for some rows but random value for others like this: `x�[o�~߯���m0��$N�k��m��~�S�_���|d�G��qmD�7拔����`

I am not sure why this happening. Is it because of casting BLOB to varchar2?

Answer (score 2):

You should do `substr` on `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2` instead of the blob column `message`. So, the final query will be like the following:

```
select dbms_lob.substr(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(message),100) from XML_MESSAGE;
```